# NaviagtionLink and withAnimation() bug

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

[Link to video of app](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Tj1h7OAs08s)

My project is having this weird bug with NavigationLink and withAnimation().
Where animation of NavigationLink, changes the view on the screen it is moving away from (see video).
The NavigationLink is in one viewController (MainView)
And the NavigationLink gets triggered from another view (MainViewPostView), via a Binding.
Maybe this is part of the problem.
Is this just a bug, or can you do something?

```
stuct MainView: View {

  var body: some View {
    mainView
  }

  private var mainView: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
              if let p = post {
                NavigationLink(destination: CommentView(post: p), isActive: $navigationViewIsActive){ EmptyView() }
              }
            }.hidden()
            
            ForEach(postViewModel.posts, id: \.id) { post in
                    MainVIewPostView(post: post, navigateToComment: $navigationViewIsActive, selectedPost: $post)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct MainVIewPostView: View {
    @ObservedObject var postRowViewModel: PostRowViewModel
    private var mainView = MainView()
    @Binding var navigationViewIsActive: Bool
    @Binding var selectedPost: Post?
    
    init(post: Post, navigateToComment: Binding<Bool>, selectedPost: Binding<Post?>) {
        self.postRowViewModel = PostRowViewModel(post: post)
        self._navigationViewIsActive = navigateToComment
        self._selectedPost = selectedPost
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            cellView
        }
    }
    
    var cellView: some View {
      Button {
          selectedPost = postRowViewModel.post
          withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
             navigationViewIsActive.toggle()
          }
     } label: {
        Image(systemName: "message")
        .font(.system(size: 26))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        
        Text("24")
           .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your video link is to a file that is located on your own machine.

Comment: @Andrew it should be fixed now

Comment: Is it normal to have inconsistencies : MainView include MainPostView which create another MainView ?

Comment: And also you only have only one navigationViewIsActive var in MainView (where is it defined ?) which is used in a loop.

Comment: Hard to tell, but I suspect "if let p = post {" is causing the problem. It'd be much better to use an Optional post variable on your CommentsView and I think this would solve your issue.