# NavigationLink gets triggered multiple times in Scrollview ForEach

Tags: swiftui, foreach, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a NavigationLink inside of a ForEach, which makes the NavigationLink gets called multiple times. I have tried many solutions to this.

For E.g. moving the NavigationLink outside the ForEach loop. However, this messes with the animation: [Look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533764/naviagtionlink-and-withanimation-bug?noredirect=1#comment128174575_72533764)

I also tried following this solution: [Look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57594890/19282494). However, I didn't understand it quite well, and couldn't make it work completely. Maybe one of you guys can rewrite it, so it makes sense in my case.

I'm open for any solutions

```
struct MainVIewPostView: View {
    @ObservedObject var postRowViewModel: PostRowViewModel
    
  var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
          ForEach(postViewModel.posts, id: \.id) { post in <- There are 4 post
                ...
        
                NavigationLink {
                        CommentView(post: postRowViewModel.post)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "message")
                            .font(.system(size: 26))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        
                        Text("24")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CommentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var commentViewModel: CommentViewModel
    
    
    init(post: Post) {
        commentViewModel = CommentViewModel(post: post)
        print("in") <- This gets called 4 times, as many times as there are post. I only want it to get called 1 time
    }
 }
```

Comment: Place NavigationLink outside of ScrollView and activate it programmatically, like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559054/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi This triggers a bug with the View: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Tj1h7OAs08s. I still haven't found a solution to this.

Comment: May not be related, but you did not put the scroll view contents in a list and VStack.